# C# Get Time Stamp with Time Zone

Tags: c#, timezone, timestamp

20120315021529.000[-8:PST]

to get the first part I was able by using below C# code.

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.fff");
```

I want some help to get machine time stamp with zone in the format of above.

+ What this kind of time formatting is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

"zzz"
Hours and minutes offset from UTC.
More information: The "zzz" Custom Format Specifier.
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -07:00 -> -07:00

So you can use:
    DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.fff[zzz]");

However, this will give you the timezone relative to UTC not to PST.

You could always read the time zone info relative to UTC and add the difference yourself.